# How to handle errors from HTTP observables

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not sure how to handle http errors in an angular2 observable.
What I have is

```
    getContextAddress() : Observable<string[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.patientContextProviderURL)
        .map((res:Response) => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

in valid URL cases, i.e. response of 200, all is well.
I am not sure why when I use a bad url, response code of 400, there is no error generate.

How do I handle that case?

Comment: What do you mean *"there is no error generate"*? Where do you subscribe to this? Do you provide the second error handling callback to the subscription? Have any logging in place to see what's happening? Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is simply re-throwing the error. Are you catching it somewhere?

For example, I have code like this:

```
this.productService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
               error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

This catches the thrown error and sets an errorMessage property that I then display in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I was not catching the error where the subscription was taking place.
My mistake